# Slidetoggle not working properly when within LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show/hide `div` on click with `slidetoggle`, its working properly but when I click on `input`, its still showing/hiding, how do I make it working only on `LI` not on inner elements.

Here is the working [JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/31nfguup/2/)

Limitation I have is I can't bring that `div` out of `LI` as currently its within `LI` tag

Here is the function I have created for that:

```
$('#location').click(function(){
    $(".location_contents").slideToggle(600);
    $(".header_right > ul > li:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('actbtn');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will trigger function while clicking parent div, it also will trigger when child is clicked, you can use immediate child selector,

```
$('#location > a').click(function(){
        $(".location_contents").slideToggle(600);
        $(".header_right > ul > li:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('actbtn');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

> I have added a class `toggleable` in `<a>` because there may be use
>   many `<a>` and in script i have selected 2 selector one `toggleable`
>   class and another one list item.

```js
$('#location .toggleable, #location ul li').click(function(){
        $(".location_contents").slideToggle(600);
  $(".header_right > ul > li:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('actbtn');
});
```

```css
/*Location Popup*/
.location_contents {background: #fff; max-width: 450px; min-width: 450px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 68px; width: 100%; z-index: 2; border-radius:4px; box-shadow:0 6px 8px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); display:none;}
.location_contents:after {bottom: 100%; left: 85%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; border-color: rgba(232, 248, 255, 0); border-bottom-color: #e8f8ff; border-width: 15px; margin-left: -15px;}
.location_contents_head {background: #e8f8ff; float: left; padding: 15px; width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box; color:#404040;}
.location_contents_head > input{width:100%; display:block; padding:8px; border:1px solid #d7d7d7; font-size:14px; color:#404040; box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset; height:45px;}
.location_contents_body{float:left; width:100%; background:#fff; padding:15px; box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;}
.location_contents_body > ul{list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.location_contents_body > ul > li{display:block; float:left; font-size:14px; color:#404040; display:block; float:left; min-width:140px; text-align:left; padding:3px 0;}
.location_contents_body > ul > li > span {padding: 4px 10px; display:inline-block; transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; border-radius: 2px;}
.location_contents_body > ul > li:hover > span {background: #0076AA; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_right">
    <ul>
        <li id="location" class="actbtn">
            <i class="ico ico_location"></i> <a href="#" class="toggleable">Delhi/NCR</a>
            <div class="location_contents" style="display: block;">
                <div class="location_contents_head"><input placeholder="Enter Your City" type="text"></div>
                <div class="location_contents_body">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Agra</span></li>
                        <li><span>Aligarh</span></li>
                        <li><span>Allahabad</span></li>
                        <li><span>Ambala</span></li>
                        <li><span>Amritsar</span></li>
                        <li><span>Bhopal</span></li>
                        <li><span>Chandigarh</span></li>
                        <li><span>Dehradoon</span></li>
                        <li><span>Delhi/NCR</span></li>
                        <li><span>Indore</span></li>
                        <li><span>Lucknow</span></li>
                        <li><span>Ludhiana</span></li>
                        <li><span>Mathura</span></li>
                        <li><span>Meerut</span></li>
                        <li><span>Patiala</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="login"><i class="ico ico_user"></i> Login</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```